# error message to display time

Tags: asp.net

Hello i have a problem with this line of code:

Last Visted On :

```
<%# Eval("LastActivityDate").Now().ToString()%>
```

I want the time the visitor last visited the website to appear using this code but i am getting this error message:

Error   3   Option Strict On disallows late binding.

Can someone help me pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't tell what data type the evaluation will produce, so you have to cast the result to DateTime:

```
<%# DirectCast(Eval("LastActivityDate"), DateTime).Now().ToString()%>
```